# Wordpress quiz plugin not getting supporting jquery and popper file?

Tags: wordpress

I have created one classes website in wordpress and in that i have used the wordpress quiz plugin and after installing it , i see that few of the functionalities is not working like no effect after click on MCQs of perticular exam question.

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed,

version 1.4.1
(index):480 GET http://demo.proserindustries.com/wp-content/themes/hestia/assets/js/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)


(index):1 Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 
'http://demo.proserindustries.com/wp-content/themes/hestia/assets/js/popper.min.js' 
with computed SHA-256 integrity 'l2cF9FVtf7NyoWlrYREvAJEYLhdhonp/8mHK+02lUdo='. 
The resource has been blocked.
(index):487 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):487
```

After page inspect i have seen following error are occurred in console and that are for the plugin is not getting jquery and popper file, so please suggest me how can i overcome this problem ?

Comment: If the files are not there then of course it wont load, the jquery cannot be found hence the 404. The issue with popper is it's trying to define an integrity, simply remove the integrity attribute from where you're calling in popper.min.js

Comment: i have made both changes but i was not the exact reason , i think there is another reason for it not working plugin?

Comment: Try disabling all plugins and see if the issue continues in the console. If it doesn't it's a theme issue not a plugin issue.